# There was an error in serializing body of message System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing this while calling soap api from server and on my local machine it is working fine. can someone please help me find out what is the exact issue.

> Exception Message:There was an error in serializing body of message
>   getAnagraficaCribisRequest: 'There was an error generating the XML
>   document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.,Inner
>   Exception:System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error
>   generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidCastException:
>   [A]BusinessProcess.NPACribis.anagraficaWsCribisRequest cannot be cast
>   to [B]BusinessProcess.NPACribis.anagraficaWsCribisRequest. Type A
>   originates from 'BusinessProcess, Version=2.0.9.15, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location
>   'F:\Appl\crsk-rs-as1-sd\RCPortal\bin\businessprocess.dll'. Type B
>   originates from 'BusinessProcess, Version=2.0.9.15, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\rcportal\6b3d45d1\d76e290b\assembly\dl3\e487bce6\29851990_1d9bd301\BusinessProcess.DLL'.

Comment: show the part of code were error occurred.

Comment: public BusinessProcess.NPACribis.anagraficaWsCribisResponse getAnagraficaCribis(BusinessProcess.NPACribis.anagraficaWsCribisRequest arg0) {
            BusinessProcess.NPACribis.getAnagraficaCribisRequest inValue = new BusinessProcess.NPACribis.getAnagraficaCribisRequest();
            inValue.arg0 = arg0;
            BusinessProcess.NPACribis.getAnagraficaCribisResponse retVal = ((BusinessProcess.NPACribis.NpaCribis)(this)).getAnagraficaCribis(inValue);
            return retVal.@return;
        }
    }